# How to trim and add the letters in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have four cases and the result should be as mentioned in the "Output".
Basic plan is the cell should not give output with ending "-", at same time if we have any "-" in between the words it should appear.

Can anybody help me one this.

[image: excel]

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I understand your query, I suggest a solution using a Helper Column. Also that you are using Excel 2016 I am using a function called TEXTJOIN available in 2016 or higher versions of Excel.

Sample data is in cells F3:F10. Adjacent is a helper column and next cell H3 is the final output.

[image]

Formula in G3 is

```
=IF(F3="-",IF(COUNTIF(F3:$F$10,"-")=COUNTA(F3:$F$10),"",IF(ISBLANK(F3),"",F3)),IF(ISBLANK(F3),"",F3))
```

Drag it down along the intended rows.

Formula in final output H3 is

```
=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,G3:G10)
```

See below how this works.

[image]

---

Solution without a helper column

See the below screenshot.

[image]

Formula in F3 is

```
=TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,E3:INDEX(E3:E10,MAX(IF(E3:E10="-",0,ROW(E3:E10)))-ROW(E2)))
```

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to create an Array Formula. The formula shall be automatically enclosed in curly braces to indicate that it's an Array Formula.

If you are staring in Row 1 then the last `-ROW(E2)` part is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this would be possible with a simple function, like `=LEFT(CONCATENATE(range,x)` with x being the last "-", but I couldn't figure out how to get x properly.

So if you are OK with VBA, you can use a "User Defined Function". Otherwise you might have to go with a helper column.

As for UDF, you can use something like this:

```
Function TrimText(value_range As Range, trim_this As String) As String
   Dim text As String, x As Long, i As Long, c As Variant
   text = ""
   i = 1
   For Each c In value_range
      text = text & c.Value
      If Not c.Value = trim_this Then x = i
      i = i + 1
   Next c

   TrimText = Left(text, x)

End Function
```

*it's just a simple loop, counting the position of the last letter*

And in the output you enter: `=TrimText(your range,"-")`

*Ignore that my language use ";" instead of "," for functions*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016+, you can use the `CONCAT` function. No need for helper columns:

```
=CONCAT($A$4:INDEX($A:$A, LOOKUP(2,1/($A$4:$A$11<>"-"),ROW(A4:A11))))
```

**Algorithm**

- Use `LOOKUP` to determine the last row in the range that does NOT contain `-`
- `A4` is the first cell (row) with data
- Use the `INDEX` function to create the last address without a hyphen

If you want to use whole column references, or a reference which might include blanks after the last hyphen (to be excluded), then modify it a bit to also exclude blanks:

```
=CONCAT($A$4:INDEX($A:$A,LOOKUP(2,1/(($A:$A<>"-")*($A:$A<>"")),ROW($A:$A))))
```

[image]